# Problems in setting gisgraphy geocoder

Tags: java, solr, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I am using Gisgraphy for building an offline geocoder. I am using [the instructions on their website](http://www.gisgraphy.com/documentation/installation/index.htm). I followed all the steps but getting these problems:

```
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [15 Feb 2013 17:21:24,795] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [15 Feb 2013 17:21:24,806] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [15 Feb 2013 17:21:24,807] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 17:52:04,415] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [16 Feb 2013 17:52:04,444] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 17:52:04,444] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 18:01:37,016] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [16 Feb 2013 18:01:37,019] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 18:01:37,019] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 21:00:07,242] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [16 Feb 2013 21:00:07,245] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 21:00:07,245] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 21:02:13,228] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [16 Feb 2013 21:02:13,231] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 21:02:13,231] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 21:03:04,803] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [16 Feb 2013 21:03:04,806] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 21:03:04,807] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 21:03:56,037] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [16 Feb 2013 21:03:56,040] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 21:03:56,040] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 21:41:57,801] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [16 Feb 2013 21:41:57,803] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 21:41:57,804] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 22:37:28,677] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [16 Feb 2013 22:37:28,681] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 22:37:28,681] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 22:54:51,368] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [16 Feb 2013 22:54:51,402] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 22:54:51,404] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 22:56:42,733] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [16 Feb 2013 22:56:42,736] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 22:56:42,737] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 23:04:54,523] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [16 Feb 2013 23:04:54,527] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [16 Feb 2013 23:04:54,528] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [17 Feb 2013 15:40:14,049] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [17 Feb 2013 15:40:14,090] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [17 Feb 2013 15:40:14,090] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [17 Feb 2013 15:40:55,009] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [17 Feb 2013 15:40:55,012] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [17 Feb 2013 15:40:55,013] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [17 Feb 2013 16:26:34,452] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [17 Feb 2013 16:26:34,504] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [17 Feb 2013 16:26:34,505] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [17 Feb 2013 16:31:32,448] (main,) : normalize_text function has generate an exception : we consider that the function is not created : org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Cannot open connection; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [???]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"); nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres")
[ERROR] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseInitializer] [17 Feb 2013 16:31:32,450] (main,) : The normalize_text does not exists, try to create it
[INFO] [com.gisgraphy.domain.repository.DatabaseHelper] [17 Feb 2013 16:31:32,451] (main,) : will create normalize_text function
```

Comment: `FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"` says that the password you provided for postgres is wrong. Are you able to login to postgres with the username and the password you are using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably have bad characters in your jdbc.properties file.  Go to commandline in windows and hit "type jdbc.properties" verify that you have no misplaced newlines or spaces, etc.  I had this exact problem and this fixed it.